# How to deal with forward slashes when using JSON in a Java/Spring application?

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

A function exists that parses JSON as it is passed in through Postman, and is used to populate an object. The object is then returned back as JSON with the help of the GSON library.

While that's great, one of the class' variables that will be populated needs to be able to deal with forward slashes (i.e. parsing `/some/address` and assign it to my class member `customer_url` and return back to the user `customer_url : /some/address`)

This works for any and all input *except* when a `/` is used anywhere in a request. Here's an example:

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/myInterface/populate/someObject/{"SOME_RANDOM_FIELD_TO_EXTRACT_STUFF_FROM": "/some/address" }`

And it returns a `404 NOT FOUND` error.

Here is my back end code in my controller if I may be making a mistake there as well:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/populate/someObject/{json}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = {
            "application/json; charset=UTF-8" })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getPopulateAndReturn(@PathVariable("json") String json) {
        JsonService jsonService = new JsonService();
        MyClass obj = populateThis(jsonService.convertJsonInputToJsonObject(json));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(gson.toJson(obj), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I have viewed the related questions but none were able to lead me to a solution nor understand the problem better.

Comment: That's... not usual. The JSON should typically be supplied as a request body.

Comment: @chrylis any examples I could look at? I tried to search for a few but not quite sure what you mean (newbie to building APIs to expose data in JSON format)

Comment: @chrylis got it. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I missed this.

So the issue is with the way the back end function interacts with the `RequestMethod`. Here is the correct function to send JSON to the application and have the application work with it in some way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/populate/someObject", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = {
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8" })
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getPopulateAndReturn(@RequestBody String json) {
    JsonService jsonService = new JsonService();
    MyClass obj = populateThis(jsonService.convertJsonInputToJsonObject(json));
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(gson.toJson(obj), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And it works as expected with populating with any `/` (forward slashes) in the request.

`@RequestBody` needs to be used to take in a JSON request. The JSON input should not be supplied directly in the URL (thank you for pointing this out, @chrylis).

When using Postman, click on the `Body` category and paste your JSON input there like so:

[image: PUT request with Postman]

Disregard the returning back of the object itself despite using a `PUT` request; wanted to test and make sure nothing else was going wrong. In the efforts of best practice, it should return just the proper `HttpStatus` (please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).